# Check if the file exists using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test()

thesentence = InputBox("Type the filename with full extension", "Raw Data File")

Range("A1").Value = thesentence

If Dir("thesentence") <> "" Then
    MsgBox "File exists."
Else
    MsgBox "File doesn't exist."
End If

End Sub
```

In this when i pickup the text value from the input box, it doesn't work. If however, if remove `"the sentence"` from If `Dir()` and replace it with an actual name in the code, it works. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

Note your code contains `Dir("thesentence")` which should be `Dir(thesentence)`.

**Change your code to this**

```
Sub test()

thesentence = InputBox("Type the filename with full extension", "Raw Data File")

Range("A1").Value = thesentence

If Dir(thesentence) <> "" Then
    MsgBox "File exists."
Else
    MsgBox "File doesn't exist."
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It helped me partially I think when I use this code compiler doesn't consider "thesentence" as a directory so I had used just one more line of code before If:

<code>Dim Path as String
Dim Directory as String
Path = InitialPath & "\" & Date$
Directory = Dir(Path, vbDirectory)
</code>
when I used ** Directory ** variable string under If Dir(Directory) <> "" then it worked well

Comment: This is my go-to method for checking if a file (or path) exists.  Consider adding error handling or ignore errors for `Dir(thesentence)` since invalid characters in the path will generate an error.

Comment: @ChrisB: `Dir` function itself will handle the error checking...did you checked?

Comment: @Cylian: You can trigger run-time error 52 with this code:  `Dir("*\")`  However unlikely an error is to occur, I prefer to handle it.  In this case, I use `On Error Resume Next` to ignore errors.  Then I assign a String variable a value using `Dir()`.  Finally I use `On Error Goto...' to resume error handling.  Depending on the intended purpose it may be desirable for the program to display the error but I prefer to handle the error with code.

Answer (score 20):

Use the Office `FileDialog` object to have the user pick a file from the filesystem. Add a reference in your VB project or in the VBA editor to `Microsoft Office Library` and look in the help. This is much better than having people enter full paths.

Here is an example using `msoFileDialogFilePicker` to allow the user to choose multiple files. You could also use `msoFileDialogOpen`.

```
'Note: this is Excel VBA code
Public Sub LogReader()
    Dim Pos As Long
    Dim Dialog As Office.FileDialog
    Set Dialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With Dialog
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .ButtonName = "C&onvert"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Log Files", "*.log", 1
        .Title = "Convert Logs to Excel Files"
        .InitialFileName = "C:\InitialPath\"
        .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList

        If .Show Then
            For Pos = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
                LogRead .SelectedItems.Item(Pos) ' process each file
            Next
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

There are lots of options, so you'll need to see the full help files to understand all that is possible. You could start with [Office 2007 FileDialog object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa432103%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (of course, you'll need to find the correct help for the version you're using).

Comment: +1 Much better, as this is excel Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

Answer (score 20):

Correction to fileExists from @UberNubIsTrue :

```
Function fileExists(s_directory As String, s_fileName As String) As Boolean

  Dim obj_fso As Object, obj_dir As Object, obj_file As Object
  Dim ret As Boolean
   Set obj_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set obj_dir = obj_fso.GetFolder(s_directory)
   ret = False
   For Each obj_file In obj_dir.Files
     If obj_fso.fileExists(s_directory & "\" & s_fileName) = True Then
        ret = True
        Exit For
      End If
   Next

   Set obj_fso = Nothing
   Set obj_dir = Nothing
   fileExists = ret

 End Function
```

EDIT: shortened version

```
' Check if a file exists
Function fileExists(s_directory As String, s_fileName As String) As Boolean

    Dim obj_fso As Object

    Set obj_fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fileExists = obj_fso.fileExists(s_directory & "\" & s_fileName)

End Function
```

Comment: Why does the code test the same file name multiple times (once for every file in s_directory)?  There is no point in repeating this test.  You will notice that the loop variable (obj_file) is not used by the loops code.

Comment: @grantnz  Indeed!  I had done the lazy copy/paste and tweaked until it worked.   Shortened version is above.  Thanks.

Comment: Has anyone noticed that sometimes this test reports a false positive, i.e. it returns ´True´ even when a file does not exist in the file system. In my application I checking the existence of a file in a server on my network, if that gives you a hint.

Answer (score 8):

just get rid of those speech marks

```
Sub test()

Dim thesentence As String

thesentence = InputBox("Type the filename with full extension", "Raw Data File")

Range("A1").Value = thesentence

If Dir(thesentence) <> "" Then
    MsgBox "File exists."
Else
    MsgBox "File doesn't exist."
End If

End Sub
```

This is the one I like:

```
Option Explicit

Enum IsFileOpenStatus
    ExistsAndClosedOrReadOnly = 0
    ExistsAndOpenSoBlocked = 1
    NotExists = 2
End Enum


Function IsFileReadOnlyOpen(FileName As String) As IsFileOpenStatus

With New FileSystemObject
    If Not .FileExists(FileName) Then
        IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 2  '  NotExists = 2
        Exit Function 'Or not - I don't know if you want to create the file or exit in that case.
    End If
End With

Dim iFilenum As Long
Dim iErr As Long
On Error Resume Next
    iFilenum = FreeFile()
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #iFilenum
    Close iFilenum
    iErr = Err
On Error GoTo 0

Select Case iErr
    Case 0: IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 0 'ExistsAndClosedOrReadOnly = 0
    Case 70: IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 1 'ExistsAndOpenSoBlocked = 1
    Case Else: IsFileReadOnlyOpen = 1 'Error iErr
End Select

End Function    'IsFileReadOnlyOpen
```

Comment: I've never heard of "speech marks" before. Strange. Kind of a misnomer in my opinion. Plenty of things require quotes but aren't speech.

Comment: @ErikE +1 for nice observation ... [Pictures Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=speech+marks&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHRG_en&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=UtQKUPS-IMqM0wWg-cyyCg&ved=0CHoQsAQ&biw=1280&bih=685)

Comment: Apparently "speech marks" is an informal version of "quotation marks".

Comment: @ErikE ...I know or rather I said "I know"

Answer (score 8):

```
Function FileExists(fullFileName As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = VBA.Len(VBA.Dir(fullFileName)) > 0
End Function
```

Works very well, almost, at my site. If I call it with "" the empty string, Dir returns "**connection.odc**"!! Would be great if you guys could share your result.

Anyway, I do like this:

```
Function FileExists(fullFileName As String) As Boolean
  If fullFileName = "" Then
    FileExists = False
  Else
    FileExists = VBA.Len(VBA.Dir(fullFileName)) > 0
  End If
End Function
```

Comment: Old post, but it looks like `dir("")` gives you the name of the first file in the current directory.  In your case it was a file called `connection.odc`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Function FileExists(fullFileName As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = VBA.Len(VBA.Dir(fullFileName)) > 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not certain what's wrong with your code specifically, but I use this function I found online (URL in the comments) for checking if a file exists:

```
Private Function File_Exists(ByVal sPathName As String, Optional Directory As Boolean) As Boolean
    'Code from internet: http://vbadud.blogspot.com/2007/04/vba-function-to-check-file-existence.html
    'Returns True if the passed sPathName exist
    'Otherwise returns False
    On Error Resume Next
    If sPathName <> "" Then

        If IsMissing(Directory) Or Directory = False Then

            File_Exists = (Dir$(sPathName) <> "")
        Else

            File_Exists = (Dir$(sPathName, vbDirectory) <> "")
        End If

    End If
End Function
```

Comment: This will give return true if you give a path and don't know if it is a directory or not. If you want to test if a path is a file only, this won't work 100%. `? dir$("C:\Users\Chloe\AppData\Local\Temp\")` will give the first file in that directory, and it will not equal "", therefore, it will return true even if you leave `Directory` argument off or set it to false.

Comment: @Chloe I guess it's assuming you will specify a file extension along with the file name so the ambiguity of being a directory doesn't really apply in that case. But sure, it could be more robust. It just depends on how deep a solution you need. But it certainly does work for the case specified by the OP

Answer (score 3):

Very old post, but since it helped me after I made some modifications, I thought I'd share. If you're checking to see if a directory exists, you'll want to add the vbDirectory argument to the Dir function, otherwise you'll return `0` each time. (Edit: this was in response to Roy's answer, but I accidentally made it a regular answer.)

```
Private Function FileExists(fullFileName As String) As Boolean
    FileExists = Len(Dir(fullFileName, vbDirectory)) > 0
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

based on other answers here I'd like to share my one-liners that **should work for dirs and files**:

- ```
  Len(Dir(path)) > 0 or Or Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) > 0  'version 1 - ... <> "" should be more inefficient generally
  ```

  - (just `Len(Dir(path))` did not work for directories (Excel 2010 / Win7))
- ```
  CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FileExists(path)  'version 2 - could be faster sometimes, but only works for files (tested on Excel 2010/Win7)
  ```

as `PathExists(path)` function:

```
Public Function PathExists(path As String) As Boolean
    PathExists = Len(Dir(path)) > 0 Or Len(Dir(path, vbDirectory)) > 0
End Function
```