# Insert dynamic hyperlink from cell reference and place it above a copied range

Tags: excel, vba, email, hyperlink

I'm running a report that gets distributed via email. In the email is a hyperlink to the report and a range of cells copied out of it as a snapshot of the report content. I'm trying to automate and found some VBA, but I'm not a programmer and can't modify it for my needs.

The VBA below gets me most of the way, but for 2 shortcomings:

1) I need the hyperlink to point to the specific file I'm referencing in the email, which changes daily (i.e. a unique workbook is created). The below uses a static hyperlink. I was trying to figure out a way to derive the hyperlink from a cell reference.

2) When copying the hyperlink and range of cells from excel into the email, I need the cells below the hyperlink. The below puts the range above the hyperlink.

I'd like to preserve the approach taken in the below VBA of referencing a worksheet to derive the email. It appears easy to deploy on other reports which get distributed.

Sub CreateMail()

```
    Dim rngSubject As Range
    Dim rngTo As Range
    Dim rngCc As Range
    Dim rngBody As Range
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
        With ActiveSheet
        Set rngTo = .Range("B1")
        Set rngCc = .Range("B3")
        Set rngSubject = .Range("B2")
        Set rngBody = .Range("H6:K22")

    End With
    rngBody.Copy
     With objMail
        .Body = "Please click on the link below..." & vbCrLf & "rngBody.Paste" & vbCrLf & _
"file:\\dbd03\nccode\Router_Proc\04Routing.txt"
    End With
    With objMail
        .To = rngTo
        .Cc = rngCc
        .Subject = rngSubject

        .Display
    End With
    SendKeys "^({v})", True

    Set objOutlook = Nothing
    Set objMail = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To make the file link dynamic, you can just include the reference of the cell, containing the file name, in the file path.

```
"<file:\\dbd03\nccode\Router_Proc\" & _
        ActiveSheet.Range(<cell address here>) & ">"
```

*Note: You might want to also check to make sure the path exists ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11573970/1698517)) before putting it in the email*

2) To paste the cells below the hyperlink, you can use another `SendKeys` combination to simulate the pressing of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd>, which will place the cursor at the end of the email. Doing this before using `SendKeys` to simulate the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> should paste the range of cells after your body text. Your updated code should be the following:

```
With objMail
    .To = rngTo
    .Cc = rngCc
    .Subject = rngSubject
    .Display
End With
SendKeys "^({END})", True '<--- Add this line HERE
SendKeys "^({v})", True
```

Another Note: Also, i don't think you need `"rngBody.Paste"` in your Body string, as this just pastes that exact text in your email body

Comment: Thank you Jaycal. I'm closer yet. However for part 1 of the answer, the result is only a partial hyperlink. 

When I add: 
"File:P:\Reports\Daily Portfolio Tracking\" & ActiveSheet.Range("L5")

It results in the hyperlink only applying to "File:P:\Reports\Daily" which is then followed by the balance in regular text. 

Is there something about having a space in the address? If so, I'm not in the position to rename our company folders.

Comment: Updated the code; This is the quick fix, but it will put brackets before and after the link. If you need to remove the brackets, then I think you'll have to leverage `.HTMLBody` instead of `.Body`

Comment: Thanks again, Jaycal! That was all I needed! This solution will be applied across several reports. A lot of time will be saved.