# Rename all worksheet names as workbook names in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

Seeking support to edit below codes in such a way that it renames all worksheets (excel) similar to their workbooknames within a folder (loop). If workbook has more than one sheet then rename it as workbookname(1),workbookname(2) etc.

```
Sub EditSheetName()
Dim NewName
NewName = Replace(ActiveWorkbook. Name, ".xl*", "")
ActiveSheet.Select
ActiveSheet.Name = NewName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just a simple loop:
I haven't figured out how to replace the ".xlsx" using a wildcard, I would assume it would be either ".xlsm" or ".xlsx", you can change them in the code

```
    Sub LoopThroughFolder()

    Dim MyFile As String, Str As String, MyDir As String, Wb As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim s As String, n As String



    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    'change the address to suite
    MyDir = "C:\Users\dmorrison\Downloads\TestFolderLoop\"
    MyFile = Dir(MyDir & "*.xls*")    'change file extension
    ChDir MyDir
    Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = 0

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open (MyFile)
        s = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        n = Replace(s, ".xls", "")    'change the file extension
        i = 1
        For Each sh In Sheets
            sh.Name = n & "(" & i & ")"
            i = i + 1
        Next sh
        ActiveWorkbook.Close True

        MyFile = Dir()
    Loop



End Sub
```

Comment: It worked for the workbook. Can you also convert this code into such a loop that it can perform the same macro on all excel files within a folder.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple sheets, you will want an if statement:

```
Dim s As String, i as Integer
If Sheets.Count=1 Then
    s = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name,".xlsx","")
    ActiveSheet.Name = s        
Else
    For i = 1 to Sheets.Count
        s = Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name,".xlsx","")
        Sheets(i).Name = s  & "(" & i & ")"
    Next i
End If
```

I have it this way so the (#) only shows up for multiple.  You would only need the loop in the Else section if you don't care.

Comment: @mechee69 Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824225/loop-through-folder-renaming-files-that-meet-specific-criteria-using-vba regarding looping through the file.  This link talks about using Collection and is a good place to get started for the file looping portion.