# VB/MS Access 2010, check if file exists

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am a newbie on VB/MS Acess. I am trying to check if a file exists but get an error. Can someone tell me whats wrong with this code:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
    On Error Resume Next
    GetDBPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\graphics\"
    If FileExists(GetDBPath & Me![Materiel_BILDNAMN]) Then
        Me![materialbildnamn].Picture = GetDBPath & Me![Materiel_BILDNAMN]
    Else
        Me![materialbildnamn].Picture = GetDBPath & "blank.jpg"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem? Error? Not returning the value properly? Does the `Me![Material_BILDNAMN]` return <fileName> **.** <extension>

Comment: I get the following error (translated from swedish): "Compiler error. Sub or function has not been defined".

Comment: also this busy question: [Check if the file exists using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11573914/8112776).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is because you are calling a function called `FileExists`, but you do not have it defined anywhere. If I am correct, the code could be found at Allen Browne's site. Here it it,

```
Function FileExists(ByVal strFile As String, Optional bFindFolders As Boolean) As Boolean
    'Purpose:   Return True if the file exists, even if it is hidden.
    'Arguments: strFile: File name to look for. Current directory searched if no path included.
    '           bFindFolders. If strFile is a folder, FileExists() returns False unless this argument is True.
    'Note:      Does not look inside subdirectories for the file.
    'Author:    Allen Browne. http://allenbrowne.com June, 2006.
    Dim lngAttributes As Long

    'Include read-only files, hidden files, system files.
    lngAttributes = (vbReadOnly Or vbHidden Or vbSystem)

    If bFindFolders Then
        lngAttributes = (lngAttributes Or vbDirectory) 'Include folders as well.
    Else
        'Strip any trailing slash, so Dir does not look inside the folder.
        Do While Right$(strFile, 1) = "\"
            strFile = Left$(strFile, Len(strFile) - 1)
        Loop
    End If

    'If Dir() returns something, the file exists.
    On Error Resume Next
    FileExists = (Len(Dir(strFile, lngAttributes)) > 0)
End Function
```

Copy the code into a **Standard Module**, give it a name something like `mod_FileCheck`. Then compile the program. It should be fine !