# How to check if file exist Ms Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, file-exists

> ```
> "I have a table "File Link" in ms access having two fields.
> I want to set the "Status" True or False if the file exist in "LINK".
> Can any body help me?"
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ---
>
> ### Link          Status
>
> C:\temp\abc.pdf    !       TRUE
> C:\temp\def.pdf    !    TRUE
> C:\temp\ghi.pdf    !    FALSE
> C:\temp\jkl.pdf    !    FALSE
> C:\temp\mno.pdf    !    TRUE
> C:\temp\pqr.pdf    !    FALSE
> C:\temp\stu.pdf    !    FALSE
> C:\temp\vwx.pdf    !    TRUE

Comment: Welcome! Did you see: [VB/MS Access 2010, check if file exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564298/vb-ms-access-2010-check-if-file-exists)?  Also check out the [tour] (you'll earn your 1st badge). Also helpful is: "how to create a [mcve]"

Answer (score 0):

[image: Form view]

[image: Form Design view]

This function does it.

=(IIf(DCount("[LINK]","FileLink","[Link] = '" & [Link] & "'")>=1,"True","False"))

1. Table name is FileLink
2. Field name is LINK
3. The third Link in the function is the name of a field in the active form

You will place the function as control source of a field on the form.