# VBA to check data link status?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to check data link status in excel?

My code changes a data link, but doesn't check to make sure that the link actually points to something useful.

```
Dim rCountryOld As Range
Dim rCountryNew As Range
Dim vLink() As Variant
Dim sDefPath As String
Dim i As Integer

With ThisWorkbook
    Set rCountryOld = .Names("CountryLink").RefersToRange
    Set rCountryNew = .Names("Country").RefersToRange
    sDefPath = Left(.Names("FileList").RefersToRange.Cells(1, 2).Value, _
        InStrRev(.Names("FileList").RefersToRange.Cells(1, 2).Value, "\") - 1)
    'check for a change in country
    If rCountryOld <> rCountryNew Then
        vLink = .LinkSources
        For i = LBound(vLink) To UBound(vLink)          'if changed, find the country datasheet link
            If UCase(Left(vLink(i), InStrRev(vLink(i), "\") - 1)) = UCase(sDefPath) Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
            .ChangeLink Name:=vLink(i), NewName:=WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rCountryNew, .Names("FileList").RefersToRange, 2, False), _
            Type:=xlExcelLinks 'change to the new country's datasheet
        rCountryOld.Value = rCountryNew.Value
    End If
End With
```

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: I'd like to specify a bit more: When the `.ChangeLink` part executes, it seem that if the new link name isn't found, the link doesn't actually change. This is the situation I'm interested in detecting

Comment: What kind of link is it?

Comment: it links to an excel WB

Comment: I suppose I can just add another if statement that compares the link's current path to the path I just tried to change it to. If that is true, I can spit out a messagebox,...

Comment: Should be easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573914/check-if-the-file-exists-using-vba