# Get data from multiple excel files into a single sheet in another file?

Tags: excel, button, vba

I have 19 files with different data sets in each file. Each file has one worksheet with 2 columns, i am trying to write a VB Macro assigned to a button [Get Output Data] - name of my button in one worksheet.

This is the code i have written to get data from one of the 19 files.

```
Sub FetchQAData()

Dim filePath As String
Dim SourceWb As Workbook
Dim TargetWb As Workbook

Set TargetWb = ActiveWorkbook

filePath = TargetWb.Sheets("Control").Range("D8").Value
Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)

       SourceWb.Sheets("results").Range("A1:B9").Copy Destination:=TargetWb.Sheets("QA model output").Range("B5:C13")

SourceWb.Close

MsgBox "RESULTS IMPORTED"

End Sub
```

The files are all stored on a central server and when i run the Macro get a Run-time error 1004 and the application doesn't recognize the file path.

Can anyone help here please?

Comment: Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11573970/1153513

Comment: Yes I did Ralph, it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the result of `Dir(filePath)`? What is value for `TargetWb.Sheets("Control").Range("D8").Value`?

Comment: I have created a directory of all files in a worksheet in the TargetWB (this is where i want the data to be copied into). This directory is in a worksheet "control". "D8" is the cell where i have entered the path of the 1st of 19 files which points to the reference SourceWb. The runtime error is in the "Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)" command, where it is not recognizing the filepath of the source file.

Comment: I understood that when you posted the question. But then it seems that the value in `filePath` or in `TargetWb.Sheets("Control").Range("D8").Value` is invalid. Hence, my question what this value is. Maybe the value in `TargetWb.Sheets("Control").Range("D8").Value` is not valid?

Answer (score 0):

Your filePath in cell "D8" must be the full path to the workbook to include the extension:  i.e. "C:\WorkbookName.xlsx" without the "" marks.

Answer (score 0):

How about this AddIn?  Try this and see if it does what you want.

http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/addins/rdbmerge.htm

[image]