# excel vba Wildcard file names: if StrFile = "test*.xlsx" then msgbox ("Confirmed")

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA is not that good so apologies in advance.
I have some vba code but cant get it to work based on filename with Wildcards. It just ignores the condition
There are over 120 excel files but I only want xlsx files that begin with specific text an example would be All_Regions.xlsx and I am trying to get a hit from a partial filename using wildcards.

I can get it to work from a static name but the issue is each week the file name will be different: All_Regions_01012018 to All_Regions_08012018 and so on each week.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Example below:

```
Sub Testing()
OPCO = "All_re*.xlsx"
Source = "C:\files\All_OPCO\"
StrFile = Dir(Source)
If OPCO = StrFile Then
    MsgBox ("Confirmed")
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573914/check-if-the-file-exists-using-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the file's search pattern within the `Dir` parameter and to test if it exists simply check that `StrFile` is not empty:

Try this:

```
Sub Testing()
    OPCO = "All_re*.xlsx"
    Source = "C:\files\All_OPCO\"
    StrFile = Dir(Source & OPCO)
    If StrFile<>"" Then
        MsgBox ("Confirmed")
    End If
End Sub
```